# What is the advantage of workdocs over s3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-workdocs

They both pretty much offers the same service and purpose, i don't see any reason why one would use workdocs over s3.

Comment: No they are not the same. I would suggest having a look at aws docs on workdocs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Amazon WorkDocs** is an online document editor and file sharing system. AWS describes it as a "fully managed, secure enterprise storage and sharing service with strong administrative controls and feedback capabilities that improve user productivity."

**Amazon Simple Storage Service (S3)** is a data storage service. AWS describes it as "storage for the internet".

To give an example:

- Amazon Workdocs is like **Google Docs**
- Amazon S3 is like **Google Drive** (sort of)

People would use WorkDocs if they wish to collaborate on documents with other people (eg review documents, add comments, share documents in a team, mount a drive of shared documents). Amazon S3 does not provide those capabilities.